# Cleartimeout multiple settimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

How could I do clearTimeout if I have multiple settimeout?
Here I have a code:

```
var $elie = $(".gear"), degree = 0, timer;


function rotate() {

    $elie.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});  
    $elie.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});                      
    $elie.css({ 'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});                      
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        ++degree; rotate();
        $('.gear').attr('timeout',timer);
    },25);
}

$(".google").hover(function() {

    clearTimeout($('.gear').attr('timeout'));


});
$(".gear").hover(function() {
    rotate();
});
```

That is: http://jsfiddle.net/T9YxL/1/
The problem is: I hover on the gear once, than hover on Google logo — everything stops as it has. But when I hover on the gear twice, I have to hover on Google logo twice and so on. How to clear all these settimeout at once even for example I hovered on the gear 100 times?

I looked here:
[clearTimeout on multiple setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425392/cleartimeout-on-multiple-settimeout)
but it didn't help.

Comment: you will overwrite the previous clearTimeout variable if you assign multiple stTimeout,best would be to make an array and loop over with clearInterval..

Comment: I'm not sure you can/should store timeouts in attributes, it's not made for that.

Comment: @Virus721: You can, timer handles are just numbers. Attributes can store numbers (as strings, but then when you retrieve them and pass them to `clearTimeout`, they get coerced back to numbers).

Comment: Then it should be `data-timeout`

Comment: @Virus721: That would be best practice, yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
timer = setTimeout(function() {
    ++degree; rotate();
    $('.gear').attr('timeout',timer);
},25);
```

should be

```
timer = setTimeout(function() {
    ++degree; rotate();
},25);
$('.gear').attr('timeout',timer);
```

and :

```
$(".gear").hover(function() {
    rotate();
});
```

should be

```
$(".gear").hover(function() {
    clearTimeout($('.gear').attr('timeout'));
    rotate();
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/T9YxL/2/)

Comment: The idea was as much you do hover it rotates faster; but on hover it has to stop. Or is it impossible with such code? I mean that the code must be more complecated, am I right?

Comment: You mean you simulate stacked `+= 1` on your `degree` angle by stacking timeout functions ? awesome :) The simpler way is to use `degree += incr` though ...

Comment: Thank you so much! That did solve the problem. So about "incr" I haven't heard yet. Thanks again!